# Corona / JSON Result

Tags: json, coronasdk, dropbox-api

I have played with `corona` and `dropbox` and I get results like the below from dropbox

I save them in a variable `t`

```
t='{
    "revision": 7,
    "rev": "707b638c6",
    "thumb_exists": false,
    "bytes": 36,
    "modified": "Fri, 24 Jan 2014 03:07:54 +0000",
    "client_mtime": "Mon, 14 May 2012 18:56:57 +0000",
    "path": "/mydays_b_12132012120312.txt",
    "is_dir": false,
    "icon": "page_white_text",
    "root": "dropbox",
    "mime_type": "text/plain",
    "size": "36 bytes"
},
{
    "revision": 9,
    "rev": "907b638c6",
    "thumb_exists": false,
    "bytes": 36,
    "modified": "Fri, 24 Jan 2014 03:08:03 +0000",
    "client_mtime": "Mon, 14 May 2012 18:56:57 +0000",
    "path": "/mydays_b_12122012120314.txt",
    "is_dir": false,
    "icon": "page_white_text",
    "root": "dropbox",
    "mime_type": "text/plain",
    "size": "36 bytes"
},
{
    "revision": 12,
    "rev": "c07b638c6",
    "thumb_exists": false,
    "bytes": 36,
    "modified": "Fri, 24 Jan 2014 18:51:43 +0000",
    "client_mtime": "Mon, 14 May 2012 18:56:57 +0000",
    "path": "/mydays_b_12132012120319.txt",
    "is_dir": false,
    "icon": "page_white_text",
    "root": "dropbox",
    "mime_type": "text/plain",
    "size": "36 bytes"
}'
```

I would like to extract all '`path`' so as result I have

```
/mydays_b_12132012120312.txt
/mydays_b_12122012120314.txt
/mydays_b_12132012120319.txt
```

I tried `corona json api`

```
local decode = json.decode( t )
print( decode.path )
```

but I only get the first Path extracted...

Any ideas?

Also I could work with another result

```
t='{
    "hash": "c6e5643fe351d4a59b4b3cb61bdfb870",
    "thumb_exists": false,
    "bytes": 0,
    "path": "/",
    "is_dir": true,
    "size": "0 bytes",
    "root": "app_folder",
    "contents": [{
        "revision": 1,
        "rev": "107b638c6",
        "thumb_exists": false,
        "bytes": 36,
        "modified": "Mon, 14 May 2012 18:56:57 +0000",
        "client_mtime": "Mon, 14 May 2012 18:56:57 +0000",
        "path": "/backup.txt",
        "is_dir": false,
        "icon": "page_white_text",
        "root": "dropbox",
        "mime_type": "text/plain",
        "size": "36 bytes"
    },
    {
        "revision": 9,
        "rev": "907b638c6",
        "thumb_exists": false,
        "bytes": 36,
        "modified": "Fri, 24 Jan 2014 03:08:03 +0000",
        "client_mtime": "Mon, 14 May 2012 18:56:57 +0000",
        "path": "/mydays_b_12122012120314.txt",
        "is_dir": false,
        "icon": "page_white_text",
        "root": "dropbox",
        "mime_type": "text/plain",
        "size": "36 bytes"
    },
    {
        "revision": 7,
        "rev": "707b638c6",
        "thumb_exists": false,
        "bytes": 36,
        "modified": "Fri, 24 Jan 2014 03:07:54 +0000",
        "client_mtime": "Mon, 14 May 2012 18:56:57 +0000",
        "path": "/mydays_b_12132012120312.txt",
        "is_dir": false,
        "icon": "page_white_text",
        "root": "dropbox",
        "mime_type": "text/plain",
        "size": "36 bytes"
    }],
    "icon": "folder"
}'
```

but does not seem easier.

It would be great if youu could give me a solution for both, to finally get all 'path' results

Thanks a lot
Chris

Comment: The first `t` is not a valid JSON string. It appears to be a list of objects but there's no array notation in there. Perhaps Corona only returns the first one because it's not processing the input as an array.

Answer (score 0):

First step I would take is to print t as such:

```
print("t: "..tostring(t))
```

It could be that t is actually a string rather than a JSON object, in which case you could conditionally substring t yourself and insert it into arrays (making your own decoder for "not really JSON" strings). If you get the expected output from the above print, comment here and I shall provide a conditional substring method if you like

Answer (score 0):

Like @Cory says the string in the first block doesn't contain valid JSON, it consists of two JSON objects after each other: *{ … }, { … }*. Corona's JSON parser apparently handles this by ignoring everything in the string after parsing the valid object.

One solution is to manually make it into a parseable JSON array by adding *[ ]* to the string, *[{ … }, { … }]*, but that's really a hack. The result from the dropbox api should never give you this malformed object.

The second block contains valid JSON and the paths can be extracted like this:

```
local json = require("json")
local foo = json.decode(t)
local content = foo.contents
for i=1,#content do
  print("PATH", content[i].path)
end
```